# Set 'view-only' shortcuts for menu items?

Tags: delphi

We know that if we set a shortcut (for example, **Ctrl + F2**) to a TMenuItem, the menu item will be executed **automatically** once the shortcut specified is pressed, and the **shortcut description** will be also shown when the menu is displayed.

But is there a way to have the shortcut descriptions visible on the menu items but make the menu don't respond to the shortcuts automatically?

You might ask me why I want this, here is the situation:

In a multiple document (like firefox's multiple tabs) program, there are multiple instances of TPopupMenu thus multiple TMenuItem objects have the same shortcuts, but I only want the menuitems in the active document window respond to the shortcuts.

---

**Edit 1**: Sorry, I wanted to simplify my question and I described it wrongly - actually, I use TActionList and link the actions to menu items.

---

**Edit 2**: Just found: I think I can use [TApplicationEvents.OnShortCut Event](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/AppEvnts_TApplicationEvents_OnShortCut.html) to intercept the shortcuts before they are being dispatched to the menus/actions... I'll try and will update my questions when I get a result.

Comment: TLama, thanks for the help. I've updated(corrected) my questions. By 'multiple instances of TPopupMenu (should be TActionList after I corrected my question)', I mean I have created multiple TFrame objects which of each contains a TActionList.

Comment: But even if it's about action list, still only one focused frame's menu will respond to the shortcut. I don't get why to intercept the shortcuts if they are described in such menu item captions. It will be confusing for users, they will be able to popup the menu, can see the shortcut, but nothing happens when they use the keystroke.

Comment: @TLama, I just verified again, with D2010, it's not the focused frame's menu will respond to the shortcut, but the unexpected frame's action will be executed and the rest will be skipped. This is actually will confuse the users. What I want to do is to avoid such confusions by centralizing the processing of the shortcuts so that only the active frame will handle the shortcuts, while still let the users see the shortcuts on the menu items by using the TAction.Shortcut property.

Comment: You should fundamentally change the design so that each frame shares a single ActionList, a single Popupmenu, etc. When a frame is selected you would define a pointer (something like PActiveDocument: ^TmyFrame). Then in the action.execute implementation you would only use your PActiveDocument. In addition you app would also use less memory.

Comment: @az01, thanks, that's an alternative approach, however, having the actions on frame gives me convenience (accessing the frame's internal data).

Comment: You're welcome but just let me push the concept a bit further. Your assumption about FireFox is totally wrong. Most of the softwares which have tabbed documents give to the end-user the feeling that the soft is designed with a **PageControl**. Actually, this is most often only a **TabControl**, which only gives the document index. To create a graphic frame for each document is, to me, a bad idea. Because, as you currently experiences it, it introduces problems.

Comment: @az01, Thanks for the explanation, actually I didn't assume anything about firefox, I take it as an example to explain the situation I'm facing. Actually, let multiple frames share a single action list is a good idea in some cases, however, in my case, the frames are not the same, and thus have different set of actions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the tab (#9) character to indicate the shorcut part of the text in standard menus. You can set the `Caption` property of the menu item or the action component that the menu item is bound to by either editing the 'dfm' or at run-time to include the tab character:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Action1.Caption :=
      Action1.Caption + #9 + ShortCutToText(ShortCut(VK_F2, [ssCtrl]));
```

Unless you also assign to the `ShortCut` property itself of the menu item or the action, the click/execute event will not be fired.

Comment: Great! The text after the tab character is even right aligned which is want I want and worrying when I first saw this solution ! Thanks Sertac! Now I know I don't have to make my own TMenuItem descent and draw the read-only shortcuts ;)